# How to override a DomainClass getter in Grails 3

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.3

I'm upgrading a Grails 2 app to 3.3.10 and we have alot of custom getters that aren't being called. Many have fallback logic for nullable values.

```
Color getFavColor(){
    if(!favColor){
        return "black"
    }

    return favColor
}
```

---

Edit: Added an actual method

```
Vendor getMarketPlaceVendor() {
    if (marketPlaceVendor) {
        return marketPlaceVendor
    }
    return campaign?.marketplaceVendor
}
```

---

Stepping into the code it appears that HibernateUtils is accessing the property directly, I can't find anyway to get around this?
`def propertyValue = reflector.getProperty(thisObject, propertyName)`

1) Is there quick fix that I'm missing?

2) What the ideal pattern here? I'm newer to grails and wondering if logic like should be moved to services.

Grails 3.3.10 | Hibernate 5 | Gorm 6.1.12.RELEASE

Comment: the getters should work fine, is it a typo that you missed the () in the method? eg: Color getFavColor() {...} It oddly may have worked as a closure(?) in 2, but not 3.

Comment: Yes that was a typo in the example. 
Breakpoints and printing out from my custom getters yields nothing. 
Also found this, maybe I'll look at downgrading Hibernate/gorm versions

https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/issues/103

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GORM 6.1 uses field access by default, which means the field is used when reading and writing data via reflection to instances.

If you wish to continue to use property access this can be configured by altering the default mapping in your configuration:

```
import javax.persistence.*
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
   '*'(accessType: AccessType.PROPERTY)
}
```

That is taken directly from our user guide at http://gorm.grails.org/6.1.x/hibernate/manual/.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like exactly what I need. It seems to have done something but unfortunately I can't confirm it's fixed my issues because now I'm getting a  "Cannot treat multi-column property as a single-column property" error that I need to look into

Comment: I'm not sure how changing the default would cause multi-column property errors but I'm hoping I can save it for a some later reading. 
I got the following to work and plan to move forward on a case-by-case basis.


`static mapping = {
        marketPlaceVendor accessType: AccessType.PROPERTY
    }`